# Single word statement written after return statement inside the function runs without an error but multiple word statement showing syntax error

Tags: python

```
def example_function():
    return 42
    hello
result = example_function()
print(result)
```

Above code is working fine but below code is giving syntax error:

```
def example_function():
    return 42
    hello hiii
result = example_function()
print(result)
```

I was expecting that both of my coding snippet will throw an error, but first one worked properly and the second one is giving syntax error. I couldn't understand why first program run without an error but the second program gave syntax error.

Comment: `hello` is valid *syntactically*. If something called `hello` did exist at the time that line would be executed, it'd be fine (though wouldn't do anything). But `hello hiii` isn't even valid *syntax*. There's no definition of what that line should do, even if both `hello` and `hiii` would be defined somewhere.

Comment: Because `hello` is valid syntax (it's just an identifier) whereas `hello hiii` is not. The position doesn't matter.

Comment: `hello` is valid syntax, it is the  name of something. If it isn't defined before the invocation of the name, it will throw a `NameError`. In this case anything after `return` in functions won't ever be executed, so it isn't evaluated and the error isn't thrown. `hello hiii` isn't valid syntax, more specifically the expression can only have meaning if `hello` is a keyword, `del hiii` is a valid expression. Python checks the syntax of the input first and won't accept any input that isn't valid syntax. Further errors are only check when the code is actually executed.